# Simple if statement for checking whether a co-ordinate is inside a square?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, if-statement

I have an UIImageView and taking the raw touch input. I need to check if a touch is within a certain set of squares. At the moment...

I have this if statement....

```
if(46 < touchedAt.x && touchedAt.x < 124 && 18 < touchedAt.y && touchedAt.y < 75)
```

but I have tried to simplify it to this one...

```
if(46 < touchedAt.x < 124 && 18 < touchedAt.y < 75)
```

It didn't work. Is it possible to simplify like this or am I stuck with the slightly lengthier version at the top? Is there a reason why the types of comparisons in the bottom `if` don't work?

Comment: Man, I wish I could accept two answers. Todd, yours is spot on. I was hoping for something like this.  

Steve, you answer is great because it explained to me why the simple one doesn't work.

Comment: Todds answer is, as you say, spot on - I'm happy with an upvote.

Comment: `(46 < touchedAt.x < 124)` is always true because the expression evaluates as '`((46 < touchedAt.x) < 124)`', and the first (inner) term evaluates to 0 or 1, and the second therefore always evaluates to true, regardless of where the touch actually is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a better solution would be to use CGRectContainsPoint:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(46, 18, 124 - 46, 75 - 18);
if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, touchedAt))
   // do whatever
```

Comment: This is a good alternative. As noted, your "shorter" syntax in the question is incorrect.

Comment: I guess this is where coming from a PHP background doesn't help sometimes. I like this alternative very much, it's a much nicer solution than what I am currently doing. However, I also like that Steve told me *why* my shorter version doesn't work.

Comment: As a general rule in Apple's APIs, any datatype defined by a framework usually has comparison functions written for it. This is especially true if the comparisons are very common such as this one. Moral: Look for the functions before writing code to duplicate them.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages support the "simple" version (Python, for example) but the C family doesn't.

In C family languages, the comparison operators are binary operators that return a boolean. One operator, two parameters, one result. Try to add another comparison and you end up comparing your boolean result against the next value. That's why you need all the `&&` operators.

I don't know Objective-C, but I assume it does what C does.

To simplify, just write a simple function (perhaps inline) called "bounds_check" or "range_check" or similar that takes three parameters. Or better still, use one that's already written.

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C. It does everything C does, exactly how C does it.

Comment: @chpwn - very interesting. I keep meaning to take a look, but you know how it is - so many languages etc. Still, I'm interested in LLVM, so I'll certainly get around to playing with clang at some time, and that has objective C support IIRC.